# Error 550 FTP Upload of same file at the same time by two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, upload, ftp

I'm having a problem in uploading files to an ftp server.
the function works fine, but if try to use it in multithread, and when two threads tries to write the same file at the same time, I got error 550 in the second thread.

basically the first thread creates the file, while the second one raises the error.

here it is my code

```
 internal bool UploadFtp(IResult result, string directoryPath, string filename, Stream fileContents, bool considerError550=true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        directoryPath = directoryPath.TrimStart('\\');
        string completePath = MachineConnectionParam.Url;

        fileContents.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        if (directoryPath != string.Empty && directoryPath != "\\")
            completePath = completePath + directoryPath;
        FtpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            completePath = completePath.TrimEnd('/');
            filename = filename.TrimStart('/');
            completePath = completePath + "/" + filename;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completePath);
            if (request == null)
            {
                result.SetError(Translate.InvalidUrl, completePath);
                return false;
            }
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            //request.Timeout = 5000;

            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MachineConnectionParam.Username, MachineConnectionParam.Password);

            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            fileContents.CopyTo(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();

            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            result.SetError(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

any idea to solve it?
thank you

Comment: So what is your problem with said behaviour? It sounds perfectly fine to me. I would EXPECT my second thread to receive an error if the first one is already writing the file.

Comment: Could be, but Upload method should overwrite the files if exists, while it raises en error in this case. That's why I'm speaking about a strange behavoiur, what if I upload a different file at the same time? (I did not have time to test it today and now the ftp is not available)

Comment: If it exists and is not blocked, then it should overwrite, yes. But it is blocked, because it is currently being written. It's like trying to delete a file while it is being copied. The file system will simply not allow it.

Comment: In other words, uploading two files at the same time should be fine. Just not the same file to the same destination two times at the same time.